# Break hasNext loop

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

I must read few Int Vector. I put it to ArrayList.
Methods to read have own class.
In main function i create object and start method readMy  which is to be put in the list of values ​​which are entered on one line separated by a space. The problem is that after the number of loops ends, it is not completed. how can I leave this loop except ctrl + d.

```
public class Wektory
{
    List<Integer> wektor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public Wektory(){}  

    public void readMy()
    {

        Scanner C=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(C.hasNextInt())
            wektor.add(C.nextInt());
    }
}
```

I checked the contents of the list and it is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if i did understand your point but you can do something like this:

```
Scanner C=new Scanner(System.in);
boolean quit = false;
while (!quit){
    System.out.println("please enter the values : \r");
    if(C.hasNextInt()){
        int value = C.nextInt();
        C.nextLine();
        wektor.add(value);
    }
    // to end you can do this or you can break directly :
    if(wektor.size() >= 10){
        System.out.println("the loop has been ended");
        quit =true;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't guess the amount of data. Maybe in other Class. Before i use Class Console read as a String split by space and add into list. But this idea turned out to be not what it was expected

Answer (score 0):

You can use a unique int value to exit the scanner e.g. -1

```
public class Wektory
{
    List<Integer> wektor = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public Wektory(){}
    public void readMy()
    {
        Scanner C=new Scanner(System.in);
        while(C.hasNextInt()){
            int val = C.nextInt();
            if(val==-1){
                break;
            }
            wektor.add(C.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i think i shouldn't set a limit for a data. Maybe in other Class. Before i use Class Console read as a String split by space and add into list. But this idea turned out to be not what it was expected